# Kafka rolling restart active controller last performance benefits

Tags: apache-kafka

Confluent and many others recommend during rolling restarts to ensure that the active controller of the Kafka cluster is restarted last:

> The active controller should be the last broker you restart. This is to ensure that the active controller is not moved on each broker restart, which would slow down the restart.

(from https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/post-deployment.html#rolling-restart)

Does anyone have experience with what the time difference is between rolling restarts saving the active controller for last vs not paying attention to it? I'm trying to understand how significant the difference is, as in my basic testing with a small test cluster of size 3 I don't see that much difference (which is to be expected since the cluster is so small)

Comment: It's not about performance or cost savings. It's about preventing client failures when controller stops

Comment: @crickey_007 can you elaborate? I haven't seen info about this before. My thoughts were since there's an election for a new controller any client interruptions would be avoided or minimal

Answer (score 3):

When the active controller is restarted, the cluster has to "elect" a new controller. When a broker is elected controller, it has to load the cluster state and be ready to handle controller duties. In practice, this usually only takes a few seconds so it's not noticable.

However you can imagine that if you keep restarting the controller, these few seconds can add and lead to a significant impact.

Restarting the controller last is a simple way to ensure that regardless the size of your cluster, a rolling restart will only trigger a single controller election.

Comment: Okay, so it sounds like to me you're saying it's only for speed reasons. Reason being is I'm writing some rolling restart functionality where I don't really care about the speed of the restart for the entire cluster (the extra 5s or so per broker is minimal), but rather the robustness/simplicity of the code, which would be a lot simpler if the ordering did not matter.

Comment: Not entirely. The faster it's over, the less disruptive it is on the cluster. So it's also improving stability.

Comment: From a general stability point of view - lower number of moving parts and steps taken lowers the chances of things going wrong. And on busy clusters with dozens or hundreds of topics it could take much longer than 5 seconds as far as I understand.